# No permission to redefine imported_procedure

Tags: import, prolog, swi-prolog, redefinition

I'm trying to create a predicate called `vertices/2` defined as:

```
vertices(G, Vs):- findall(V, vertex(G, V), Vs).
```

When I consult my file prolog gives me the error:

> No permission to redefine imported_procedure `ugraph:vertices/2'

How can I avoid the redefinition?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWI-Prolog provides a `ugraphs` library module, not `ugraph`. I assume that's only a typo?

Assuming that you're loading `ugraphs` library module in the same context as your `vertices/2` predicate, why not simply rename your predicate? E.g. `my_vertices/2`. Another possible option would be for you to load the `ugraphs` module without importing its predicates by using:

```
:- use_module(library(ugraphs), []).
```

This will solve the conflict but will also require that you call the `ugraphs` module predicate using explicit qualification.

It may also be the case that the `ugraphs` module is not being loaded explicitly by you but as a consequence of other modules that you may be loading. If that's the case, turn on verbose auto-loading to find out why the module is being loaded:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(verbose_autoload, true).
```

Comment: Hi, yes i meant ugraphs, i tried to use the directive :- use_module(library(ugraphs), []).  and i added before my predicate the name of the file, like pcmin:vertices...  now the error is gone. I couldn't change the name because it's a school project and i have to follow my professor's instructions

Answer (score -1):

For everyone else that is getting this error, as this is the first page you find if you serch for `No permission to redefine imported_procedure prolog swi`.

What is happening to you is that probably you created a fact as `sumlist([],0).`, but sumlist is a name already used inside a module so you are modifing a procedure that already exist, what you have to do is use a name that is not already taken ( for example call it `mysumlist` instead of `sumlist` )